# Definition of algebraic structure

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition, lattice-orders

Is there a definition of *algebraic structure*? [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_structure) says:

> a set (called carrier set or underlying set) with one or more finitary operations defined on it.

In particular, what is the motivation to say that a lattice is an algebraic structure, but not saying that a poset is an algebraic structure? Are they too boring? Referring to wikipedia, the term "one or more finitary operations" seems to hold for almost everything I know.

Comment: A poset is a *relational* structure, i.e. relations are allowed in addition to operations. Algebraic structures allow only operations, no relations. See the Wikipedia article on [Structure (mathematical logic)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_%28mathematical_logic%29)

Comment: you might be confusing relations with operations.  Posets have relations defined on them, like "<", while algebraic structures have operations like addition or multiplication.

Comment: ah of course...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A poset has a structure, but not an algebraic structure.  A poset is equipped with a partial order relation, this is not a finitary operation.  For a set $S$ an $n$-tary operation is a function $F:S^n\to S$. An order relation is not a function.

Comment: "An order relation is not a function." Actually, a decidable order relation can be viewed as a function from $S \times S$ to $\operatorname{bool} = \left\{\operatorname{true}, \operatorname{false}\right\}$. It's just not a function to $S$.

Answer (score 2):

I know that in literature is far easier to find definitions of *magma*, *groupoid*, *binary operation*, etc., rather than a definition of *algebraic structure*.

One that may fit is the following.

> An **algebraic structure** is a totally ordered set, whose elements are
>
> - sets $S_i$,
> - (finitary) operations $O_j$ over these sets,
> - relations $R_k$ between these sets.

I wish I'll add a reference soon (sorry for only translating [this page](http://progettomatematica.dm.unibo.it/AlgebraLineare/diz2/stralg.htm) back from my native language, italian).

Related, [this definition](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Algebraic_system) includes relations, as the above. And the bibliography at the bottom of this latter may give you a further hand.

An example of structure with more than one set is a vector space $\mathrm{W}$ over a field $\Bbb K$: $(\mathbb{K},\mathrm{W},+,\times)$.

An example of structure with also a relation is an ordered field: $(\mathbb{K},+,\cdot,\le)$.